# How do I load data using ObservableObject in SwiftUI?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, swiftui, combine

I am trying to transition an app from UIKit to SwiftUI which depends on basic DynamoDB resources but I have hit a snag in forcing the view to refresh as data is added to the list. I have been at this set of code for hours trying different things and I thought I might see if anyone might know why the 'SessionsData' seems to be thrown away and will not accumulate the 'Sessions' objects.

Does anyone have any quick thoughts???

```
class SessionsData: ObservableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionsData, Never>()
    @Published var data: [Sessions] = [] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

    init() {
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        scanExpression.limit = 20

        var temp : [Sessions] = []

        dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Sessions.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                 print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
             } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
                for session in paginatedOutput.items as! [Sessions] {
                    print("Item Found")
                    temp.append(session)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = temp
                    self.didChange.send(self)
                }
             }
            print(self.data.count)
            return true
         })
    }
}
```

```
struct Events: View {

    @ObservedObject var sessionsData = SessionsData()


    var body: some View {...}
}
```

Comment: as you ask, some "quick thoughts"
1. I'm using ```@EnvironmentObject``` for variable, which I need to observe;
2. And using ```.onReceive(...``` method (in your case it should be something like: ```.onReceive(self.sessionsData.didChange...``` in struct ```Events```)

Comment: Do you think those variables in load will all survive after init? do you need save some as instance variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've over-complicated the code. The `PassthroughSubject` is unnecessary. Whenever you change a `@Published` property, it should trigger an update.

```
class SessionsData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var data: [Sessions] = []

    init() {
        load()
    }

    func load() {
        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        scanExpression.limit = 20

        var temp : [Sessions] = []

        dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Sessions.self, expression: scanExpression).continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
            if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                 print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
             } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
                for session in paginatedOutput.items as! [Sessions] {
                    print("Item Found")
                    temp.append(session)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.data = temp
                }
             }
            print(self.data.count)
            return true
         })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with DynamoDB, but here are a few things from SwiftUI / Combine perspective. In `ObseravbleObject`s have change a significant bit and and are now declared with `objectWillChange` and then sending `newValue` in `willSet`:

```
class SessionsData: ObservableObject {

    public let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<[Sessions], Never>()

    public private(set) var items: [Sessions] = [] {
        willSet {
            objectWillChange.send(newValue)
        }
    }

    init() {
        self.items = []
    }

    public func load() {
        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        scanExpression.limit = 20

        var temp: [Sessions] = []

        dynamoDBObjectMapper
            .scan(Sessions.self,
                  expression: scanExpression)
            .continueWith(block: { (task:AWSTask<AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput>!) -> Any? in
                if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                   print("The request failed. Error: \(error)")
                } else if let paginatedOutput = task.result,
                    let sessions = paginatedOutput.items as? [Sessions] {
                    temp.append(contentsOf: sessions)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.items = temp
                }
            }
            return true
         })
    }
}
```

For the UI part you have to just call your load() method defined above in `.onApear()` and everything else should happen magically:

struct Events: View {

```
@ObservedObject var sessionsData: SessionsData

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(self.sessionsData.items) { session in
            Text(session.name) // or something of that kind
        }
    }   .onAppear(perform: { self.sessionsData.load() })
}
```

}